# Mean value theorem does not hold for the complex function $f(z)=z^3$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f(z)=z^{3}$, two point $z_{1}=1$ and $z_{2}=i$.

show that Do Not exist a point $c$ on the $y=1-x$ between $1$ and $i$

such that Do Not satisfying ${f(z_{2})-f(z_{1})\over z_{2}-z_{1}}=f'(c)$.

**I tried it.**

my pf)

$f'(z)=3z^{2}$ and ${f(z_{2})-f(z_{1})\over z_{2}-z_{1}}={-i-1\over i-1}=$**$i$**.

suppose exist a point $c$, $f'(c)=3c^{2}=i$.

but the point $c$ exist on $y=1-x$.

so, minimum of modulus of $c$ is $\sqrt{2}\over 2$. ( length of $Origin$ and $y=1-x$ )

But modulus of $3c^{2}=i$ is ${\sqrt{3}\over 3}$ which less than $\sqrt{2}\over 2$.

therefore NOT exist $c$.

**My proof is all right? I think that all right.... but and you?**

Comment: $f(z_1) = 1$, not i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. A bit more concisely: for every $z$ on the line segment between $1$ and $i$
$$|f'(z)|= 3|z|^2 \ge 3 (1/\sqrt{2})^2 = \frac32  $$
whereas 
$$
\left|\frac{f(i)-f(1)}{i-1}\right| = \left|\frac{-i-1}{i-1}\right| = 1
$$